# How to check today is Monday in Perl ?

Tags: perl, perl-module

How can I check if today is Monday in Perl?

What modules needs to be installed?

Can anyone help me with an example?

Comment: Please show some effort and tell us what you have tried and where your problems were with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html). It returns a list of values. The seventh of these is the weekday, starting at Sunday. Thus, Monday has the value 1. If no argument is given, it uses the current time ([`time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html)), which is what you want.

```
if ( (localtime)[6] == 1) {
  print "Today is Monday!\n";
}
```

Since we only need the index 6 (seventh return value), we can put parens around `localtime` to force it into a list, and access the index directly from that list. We can compare that scalar value to `1`.

`localtime` is a built-in function. No need for any additional modules, not even one included in the Perl Core. This just works out of the box.

Comment: I have given my code as :

#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
 [% IF (localtime)[6] == 1 %]
  print "Today is Monday!\n";
[% ELSE %]
print "hello";
[% END %]
throws error [Wed May 29 15:12:44 2013] abc.cgi: Global symbol "%IF" requires explicit package name at abc.cgi line 15.
 >>abc.cgi: syntax error at abc.cgi line 15, near "% IF ("
>> abc.cgi: Global symbol "%ELSE" requires explicit package name at abc.cgi line 18.

Comment: What you are doing is not Perl code. It's Template Toolkit and will not work in a `.pl` file.

Answer (score 4):

If you want more "human" (actually object-oriented) way to access data from `localtime`, use `Time::Piece`'s version of `localtime` ([`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) is core module since perl 5.10):

```
use v5.10;
use Time::Piece qw(localtime);

my $t = localtime;
if ($t->day_of_week == 1) {
   say 'Today is Monday, too!';
}
```

You can also look into docs and use:

> ```
> $t->wday                # 1 = Sunday
> $t->_wday               # 0 = Sunday
> $t->day_of_week         # 0 = Sunday
> $t->wdayname            # Tue
> $t->day                 # same as wdayname
> $t->fullday             # Tuesday
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the DateTime module.

```
use DateTime;

if ( DateTime->today->day_of_week == 1 ) {
    print "Today is monday\n"
}
```

If your monday starts at 0 you can use day_of_week_0

```
if ( DateTime->today->day_of_week_0 == 0 ) {
    print "Today is monday\n"
}
```

Comment: DateTime isn't in core perl, plus it's quite heavy.